# Open Context Menu with Angular when a Context Menu is already open

Tags: angular

I tried to accomplish something as in this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-context-menu?file=app%2Fcontext-menu-example.html)

So far so good. It also works in my app like it is done there. There is one thing I don't like and do not seem to find an answer. If I do

- right click to open context menu on item3

  - opens context menu from app
- now without closing it, right click on item 1

  - opens context menu of Browser

[image]

Is there a way to enforce every right click to open my own context menus?